# Posts.xml doesn't contain tags information

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, data-dump

For a personal project I'm using stack overflow data dump in order to make suggestion to the user using StackOverflow's posts.
In this work I need also to retrieve information about tags which were setted to the specific post. So my question is really really simple and comes naturally: Why aren't present tags information in the Posts.xml file?
In the DataExplorer I'm able to make some queries using that information but in the data dump that I've downloaded isn't present the attribute *Tags* in the **row** xml element.

Comment: Tags are only attached to questions -- not to posts (which include answers and other miscellany). Is there some reason you cannot just query the tags portion of the questions table for posts which are categorized as a question?

Comment: Do you mean? I'm not able to retrieve this questions' information that you've said. Please, can you give me an example of that?
Actually I'm downloading the csv result file from each table contained in the data explorer in order to use them for my project.
It should be the same as using xml files.

Comment: Take an answer on SE. For instance [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15560520/1933347). The post ID is 15560520. I can view it by going to http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15560520 or view it in the API using [this query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=15560520&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true). One of the items in the xml for that query is `"question_id": 15545596`.

Comment: If I [query that question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=15545596&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) then I get the following tags: `"tags": ["javascript","html","google-visualization","google-charts-api","google-chartwrapper"],`

Comment: But I'm not talking about the online data explorer, with it I didn't have any problem. I'm referring to the stack overflow data dump which is in xml format and doesn't present information about the tags.

Answer (score 1):

The Posts.xml file will contain both Questions and Answers. Questions will have the Tags attribute, Answers won't.

So the structure of a typical [Post.xml](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/meta.beer.stackexchange.com.7z) file will look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<posts>
  <row Id="1" PostTypeId="1" Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;&lt;scope&gt;&lt;homebrew&gt;" AnswerCount="3"/>
  <row Id="2" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="1"  />
  <row Id="3" PostTypeId="1" Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;&lt;scope&gt;" AnswerCount="2" CommentCount="0" />
  <row Id="4" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="7" Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;" AnswerCount="2" CommentCount="0" />
  <row Id="6" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="4" />
  <row Id="7" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="4" />
</posts>
```

Here you see rows with attributes `PostTypeId="1"` which denotes questions. Those rows do have a `Tags` attribute. The rows with `PostTypeId="2"` denote answers. Those rows lack the `Tags` attribute but they do have a `ParentId` attribute that links the answer to its question.

Notice that the Tags attribute store all tags and each tag is surrounded by a < and >.

So the following content of a tag attribute:

> ```
> Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;&lt;scope&gt;&lt;homebrew&gt;"
> ```

signifies that the question has 3 tags:

1: [discusson](/questions/tagged/discusson) 2: [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) 3: [homebrew](/questions/tagged/homebrew)

The datadump doesn't have a posttags.xml, a table that is available in SEDE and links the Tags.xml/table to its Posts.xml/table. If you need that table in your local db you have to postprocess posts.xml anf tags.xml so you build up the posttags table yourself.